# Get eBay Suggestions For Search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ebay-api

I'm trying to get eBay suggested values for searching purposes against the given keyword. A prototype can be found **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qye2Z/1/)**. Can anyone help me to figure out the problem in code?

Comment: You have a same-origin policy problem, you can't make AJAX requests to another domain for security reasons. JSONP and CORS are ways to work around it, but i've never used them so can't help you solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to the Same Origin Policy - you cannot make an AJAX call to any domain other than the current, unless the format of the request is JSONP.

The workaround is to use a server-side proxy on your domain (such as in [this example](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ajax-and-xml-issues-no-element-found)) to get the XML file, and then have your jQuery load that.